# split colon in view page using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui, kendo-grid

I want replace colon in view page using angularjs.
  For example i have some unique data like that

```
$scope.PlayerList =[{
    "ID" : "111:Player",
    "Name" : "Rasberry, Jackson (16U Blue)",
    "Type" : null
}, {
    "ID" : "112:Player",
    "Name" : "Keller, Jacob",
    "Type" : null
}]//This is my list
```

Here is my html

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in PlayerList track by $index">
    <input type="ceckebox" id="{{item.ID}}">


<!--Real out put is like that  <input type="checkbox" id="111:Player">  -->
 But i want to like <input type="checkbox" id="111Player">
</div>
```

I want to omit colon(:) in view page using angularjs without change $scope.layerList properties 
If you have any idea please help me.........................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a filter to achieve the results. Update code to following

```
<input type="ceckebox" id="{{item.ID | customText}}">

.filter('customText', function() {
  return function ( input ) {
    return input.split(":").join('');
  };
})
```

Comment: Thanks you for your sweet answer.I have solve this problems using your custom function.Sai ho